# How do you generate links for paginator in Perl?

Tags: perl, http

Each link has the same url as the current requested uri except that the `page` parameter may differ.

How do you generate such links in Perl?

Comment: Are you serious? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not seem to know the basics. Go read an introductory book or two about Web programming.

1. Construct a URI object.

   ```
   use URI qw();
   ```

   - In CGI, piece it together [from the enviroment](http://p3rl.org/CGI#FETCHING_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES). (Stackers, is there a better way/convenience method I've overlooked?)

     ```
     my $current = 'http://example.com/?search=foobar';
     my $u = URI->new($current);
     ```
   - In PSGI, use the [`uri`](http://p3rl.org/Plack%3a%3aRequest) method.

     ```
     use Plack::Request qw();
     …
     my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
     my $u = $req->uri;
     ```
   - Higher-level frameworks should provide their own accessors. In Catalyst:

     ```
     my $u = $c->request->uri;
     ```
2. Mutate the query string to include the [paging](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aPage) parameter.

   ```
   use URI::QueryParam qw();
   $u->query_param(page => 13);
   $u->as_string; # returns  http://example.com/?search=foobar&page=13
   ```
3. The `query_param` DTRT and overwrites the parameter even if it's already set.

   ```
   $u->query_param(page => 42);
   $u->as_string; # returns  http://example.com/?search=foobar&page=42
   ```